# Stored procedure calculating tax rate

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I was learning stored procedure using some example.

Create a table `Employee` with the columns social security no. (primary key), name, position, no. of dependents, annual salary.

Write and execute a T-SQL stored procedure `Compute_Tax` to do the following:

- Create a new table `Tax` with columns social security no., income tax
- Fill the table `Tax` with data by computing the income tax for each person in the `Employee` table

The income tax is computed from the annual salary S and the number of dependents D.

```
Net Salary:  S - (7000 + D*950)
Tax Computed as follows:
10% of the first 15,000 of net salary;
plus 15% of the next 15,000 of net salary;
plus 28% of any net salary over 30,000.

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `computeTax`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE ssn NCHAR(20);
    DECLARE noOfDependent INT;
    DECLARE annualSalary DOUBLE;
    DECLARE netSalary DOUBLE;
    DECLARE tax DOUBLE;

    DECLARE empCur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT socialSecurityNumber, noOfDependents, annualSalary FROM `dbTest`.Employee;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN empCur;
    FETCH empCur 
        INTO ssn, noOfDependent, annualSalary;

     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TAX
        (ssn VARCHAR(20), 
        incomeTax DOUBLE
        );  


        myLoop: LOOP

            SET netSalary = annualSalary - (7000 + noOfDependent * 950);

            IF (netSalary < 0 ) THEN
                LEAVE myLoop;
             END IF;   

            IF (netSalary < 15000) THEN
                SET tax = 0.1 * netSalary;

            ELSE IF (netSalary > 15000) THEN

                    IF (netSalary > 30000) THEN

                        SET tax = 0.10 * 15000 + 0.15 * 15000 + 0.28 * (netSalary - 30000);
                    ELSE

                    SET tax = 0.10 * 15000 + 0.15 * (netSalary -15000);

                  END IF;     
           END IF;
      END LOOP myLoop;
      INSERT INTO TAX(ssn, incomeTax) VALUES(ssn, tax);  

    FETCH empCur 
        INTO ssn, noOfDependent, annualSalary;
    CLOSE empCur;
  END;
```

I am getting some syntax error on the last **END** and **END Loop myLoop** above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two problems:

- You use `SET done = true` but you don't DECLARE a variable called `done`.
- You start a nested `IF / THEN / END IF` statement inside your `ELSE` block, but you have only one `END IF`.

  Note that `ELSE IF` is different from `ELSIF` in the stored procedure language. The former starts a new `IF` statement nested within the `ELSE` block of the outer statement. The latter continues the existing `IF/THEN/END IF` statement.

  You need to structure it like one of the following:

  ```
  IF ... THEN
    <code>
  ELSE 
    <code>
    IF ... THEN
      <code>
    END IF;
    <code>
  END IF;
  ```

  Or alternatively:

  ```
  IF ... THEN
    <code>
  ELSIF ... THEN
    <code>
  END IF;
  ```

For what it's worth, I don't use MySQL stored procedures. They're terribly inefficient in most cases, and they don't support packages, or a debugger, or many other good features of stored procedures in other RDBMS products like Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server.

I don't recommend using stored procedures in MySQL just because you're accustomed to using them in other database platforms. It's much easier to develop in a scripting language like Ruby or Python.